# A Collection Per User or A Collection of Users

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to figure out which is the best option for storing individual user logging information and general meta profiling data for each user on our system.

The original idea was to have a "profiler" collection and each document would represent a user. The problem with this design is that a power user could rack up so much meta data and history over the course of a year or less that it exceeds the document size limit. It also would force the documents to have deeper and more complex structures, which could result in slower queries.

The alternative design idea is to create a collection for each user and each document would hold specific types of profiling, history data. There are several benefits to this, namely speed. Yet also presents querying challenges when needing to run comparisons against other users (Solvable through other tracking DBs). I can't find a definitive answer to the question of how many collections a single mongo database contain.

If it can handle millions upon millions of collection per database then fantastic, otherwise I need to find better options for modeling this data. Am I going about this the right way?

The goal is to maintain a history of a user's interactions, reputation tracking, their interests over time, features they use regularly etc. which can allow for a more rich experience.

Comment: Collection of users + indexing is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 2 collections: Users & User interactions.

There are certain things that make complete sense to store inside a User's document:

- Reputation tracking
- Interests -- common tags (similar to stack overflow) that a user frequents
- Features -- this should be a finite list items.  You could Key and $increment them as they are used

*User interactions* on the other hand is more of a log type structure that you may want to store with a back reference and process later.

Also check out [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) -- It's a distributed queuing technology that LinkedIn uses to do something similar to what you are describing.